# Quotient Group $U(1)/\mathbb{Z} $

Tags: real-analysis, group-theory, irrational-numbers, group-homomorphism, quotient-group

Define a homomorphism $f_t$ from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $U(1)$ by 
$$f_t: n \rightarrow \exp {(i2\pi n t)},\,\,\,\,\,\, n\in \mathbb{Z}$$
where $t\in[0,1)$. Obviously if $t=1/m$ with $m\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, the quotient group $U(1)/\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $U(1)$. I think this can be generalized to the case when $t$ is a rational number between $0$ and $1$. My question is if $t$ is an irrational number, what is the quotient group $U(1)/\mathbb{Z}$?

Any comment, proof, or references will be appreciated!

**NOTE:** I made a stupid mistake here. For $t\in \mathbb{Q}$, the image of the map $f_t$ is not $\mathbb{Z}$. But I think for irrational $t$, the image will be $\mathbb{Z}$. So I think $\mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup of $U(1)$. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What is $U(1)$ here?

Comment: @GuidoA. It is a group $\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z| = 1\}$ with standard multiplication.

Comment: The quotient is $\cong \Bbb R/(\Bbb Z+t\Bbb Z)$, so indeed is $\cong \Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ for $t\in\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Something is not right How is $\mathbb{Z}$ a subgroup of $U(1)$? (assuming the unit circle defintion given by Seewoo Lee) so what do you mean by quotient group $U(1)/\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I assume Seewoo means the quotient by the image of the map.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen What is the quotient $\mathbb{Z}+t \mathbb{Z}$? Maybe my question is: what do you mean by $\mathbb{Z}+t \mathbb{Z}$? Do you mean a direct sum?

Comment: @AnuragA Thanks for your comment. I indeed made a mistake. Please ignore my statement when $t$ is rational. However, I think for $t$ being irrational, $f_t$ is still an injective map to from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $U(1)$, making $\mathbb{Z}$ a subgroup of $U(1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $e^{i2\pi \theta}\mapsto e^{i2\pi  \theta/t}$ is a homomorphism from $U(1)$ onto $U(1)$ that has kernel given by the image of the map you specified above. By the first isomorphism theorem, we see that the quotient group is $U(1)$.